# I need to display the third <li> in BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape a page Web, the problem that I can't scrape the third item, I managed to display the first item with this code :

```
repo = soup.find(class_="search-results-list")

Num_pieces = repo.ul.li.string
```

I have this HTML code and I want item "101" :

[image]

Comment: please don't post images of html. Use the snippet tool via [edit] to add html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below code.Hope it will work.

```
repo =soup.find('div',class_="search-results-list").find_all('li')[2]
print(repo.text.strip())
```

OR

```
repo =soup.find('ul',class_="item-tags").find_all('li')[2]
print(repo.text.strip())
```

Answer (score 0):

how about like this?

```py
repo = soup.find(class_="search-results-list")
Num_pieces = repo.find("li:nth-child(3)").getText()
```

Comment: nth-of-type should work e.g. print(soup.select_one('.search-results-list li:nth-of-type(3)').text.strip()) #entire contents   or 
print(soup.select_one('.search-results-list li:nth-of-type(3)').text.strip().split('\n')[0]) #101 only.  If return is empty then first parent element with that class is not the one to target and you need to supply an index for the right parent.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
lol = soup.find('ul', {"class": "item-tags"}).findAll('li')[2]
print(lol.text.strip())
```

Explanation: So what this code does is, it finds the `ul` tag with the class `item-tags`. `soup.findAll` returns a list so we need the 3rd one, where 101 is situated, hence index `2`. Note we want to extract the text. Thats it.